# Rank products based on average score, number of reviews and price

Tags: php, sorting

I already asked this on https://math.stackexchange.com but they said I better could ask it here. I got the following data:

```
$average_score
$max_score = 5
$min_score = 0.5
$total_reviews
$price
```

I dont got data how many "good" reviews or "bad" reviews there are. Just the average, total and min and max score you can give.

I got a query like this:

```
<?php
return array(
    'post_type' => 'page',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => 10,
    'facetwp' => true,
    'meta_query' => array(
        'featured_sort' => array(
            'key' => 'featured',
            'compare' => 'EXISTS'
        ),
        array(
            'key'       => 'package-or-service',
            'value'     => array('hosting'),
            'compare'   => 'IN',
        ),
        'price_sort' => array(
            'key' => 'price',
            'type' => 'DECIMAL(10,2)',
            'compare' => 'EXISTS'
        ),
        'average_score_sort' => array(
            'key' => 'average_score_count',
            'type' => 'DECIMAL(10,2)',
            'compare' => 'EXISTS'
        ),
    ),
    'orderby' => array(
        'featured_sort' => 'DESC',
        'average_score_sort' => 'DESC',
        'price_sort' => 'ASC'
    )
);
```

The average_score_sort is calculated like this:

```
$average_total = $average_score * $count_reviews / 100;
```

I also tried it like this for just average ranking and review count (without price included)

```
$average_total = ($count_reviews/5)/($count_reviews/$average_score)*($count_reviews);
```

but that basicly does the same.

I know this is not the best way but I dont know how to sort this in a good way. I know there is something like the Wilson Interval but dont know how to use that in this case and also include the price as a sorting factor.

The results are now sorted like this (Company's have multiple products):

1. Company 1 Product - Price 4,99 - 10 reviews - average 5
2. Company 1 Product - Price 9,99 - 10 reviews - average 5
3. Company 1 Product - Price 19,99 - 10 reviews - average 5
4. Company 2 Product - Price 1,00 - 9 reviews - average 4.7
5. Company 2 Product - Price 2,00 - 9 reviews - average 4.7
6. Company 2 Product - Price 4,00 - 9 reviews - average 4.7
7. Company 2 Product - Price 8,00 - 9 reviews - average 4.7
8. Company 2 Product - Price 16,00 - 9 reviews - average 4.7
9. Company 2 Product - Price 32,00 - 9 reviews - average 4.7

As you can see this is not quite fair and I want to sort the results based on average and the number of reviews and also on price from low to high. So that it would more something like this:

**EDIT**

1. Company 1 Product 1 - Price 0,45 - 507 reviews - average 4.9
2. Company 2 Product 1 - Price 1,00 - 151 reviews - average 4.7
3. Company 2 Product 2 - Price 2,00 - 151 reviews - average 4.7
4. Company 3 Product 1 - Price 2,00 - 973 reviews - average 4.6
5. Company 4 Product 1 - Price 2,00 - 344 reviews - average 4.5
6. Company 1 Product 2 - Price 4,49 - 507 reviews - average 4.9
7. Company 5 Product 1 - Price 3,99 - 97 reviews - average 4.9
8. Company 6 Product 1 - Price 2,50 - 9 reviews - average 4.4
9. Company 2 Product 3 - Price 4,00 - 151 reviews - average 4.7

Is this possible with the data I got so far?

Comment: I dont get the logic in the 2nd order system? Why is `Company 1 Product - Price 19,99 - 10 reviews - average 5` in 7th place?

Comment: "As you can see this is not quite fair" -> seems to me much fairer than having something ranked higher with **more reviews** being classed after something worse ranked with less reviews. IMO having more reviews tend to bring the score farther from extremes limits, so having a good rank with lots of reviews is a pretty good sign, not the contrary

Comment: @Loko, Maybe this was not the best example. What I try te realise is a sorting based on average reviews and review count. And also make a sorting on price. I edited my question with a new sorting example. If you look at result 5,6 and 7 and how they are ordered. Result 6 has the same average score, higher price but a lot more reviews so it is ranked above result 7. Does this make more sense? The ordering has to be a combination of average, total reviews and price. Is this possible?

Comment: @Kaddath This was a poor example, I edited my answer, does this make more sense to you?